# Getting Partial Chain exception for Azure Function App to https(APIM) endpoint call using public intermediate cert

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-functions, httpclient

I am trying to make https call using HttpClient in the azure function app(C#) running in Linux OS.

The cert(.cer) is a CA signed intermediate cert(with chain to root cert) uploaded in the Public Certificates of Function App to be used in the function app.

[image]

Here is the Function App Code I am using to create HttpClient:

```
 static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        string certificatePath = "var/ssl/certs/certificatethumprint.der";          

        if (certificatePath == null) {
            throw new Exception("Environment Variable is null");
        }
        HttpClient httpClient = null;
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath);
        X509Certificate2 cert = new(bytes);
        handler = new HttpClientHandler();           
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        }           
        return httpClient;
    }
```

Here is the code using httpClient:

```
 static HttpClient httpClient = GetHttpClient();


 HttpRequestMessage httpWebRequest = GetHttpRequest(messageBody, log);
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                try {
                    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpWebRequest);
                }
```

Get HttpRequest returns the HttpRequest with request parameters.

While I use the code above I am getting this exception:

> Exception occurred during http call:
> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> stackTrace: at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
> at Function.FunctionApp.FunctionApp.Method(Parameter parameter) in /opt/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.173.0.tar.gz/_work/1/s/Function/Function.FunctionApp/FunctionApp.cs:line 116
> type: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
> InnerException: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The message in exception:

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

I do not want to force validate the cert using the code below as I'll need to deploy this in production and it is not the best practice for production environment:

```
 handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true; //Not a best practice/ not safe
            },
            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
        };
```

Any suggestion/help would be much appreciated.

Based on the suggestion, when I didn't use any cert to make https call from client I get this exception:

> Error when sending the http request: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> Information
> 2022-11-23 19:11:56.999
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm) at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessa

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting to a secure server, only the server needs a certificate. I don’t fully understand what you are doing with HttpClient and servers, but at least in the GetHttpClient(), I don’t think there is a need to set the certificate yourself. Hope this helps!